# Excel: How to search for a word?

Tags: excel, search, filter, find

I have a column with a couple of words in each row of that column. Now I need to search if a separate word exists in that phrase.

I tried using the Search() function but it is displaying result even if the word is part of a word and not a separate word.

For Ex: If I use Search("mart",). it even returns cells containing words like jmart. But what I want it to return is like if a cell contains "hello mart" or "mart abc"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in question that there are only two words in a cell, then this should help. Enter any of the following formulas in `Cell B1`

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(" mart",A1)),IF(ISERR(SEARCH("mart ",A1)),"",SEARCH("mart ",A1)),SEARCH(" mart",A1))
```

-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" mart",A1)),SEARCH(" mart",A1),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("mart ",A1)),SEARCH("mart ",A1),""))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference

[image]

Comment: B2 should return 1 as well as "mart" is a word by itself.

Comment: @RowenChumacera - My solution is based on the sample provided by OP that states *couple of words in each cell*. I know `B2` does not return anything and hence to let OP know that, I've included it in my sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula:

```
=IF(SEARCH("mart", A1)>1,  IF(AND(MID(A1, SEARCH("mart", A1)-1, 1)=" ", OR(MID(A1, SEARCH("mart", A1)+4, 1)=" ", (SEARCH("mart", A1)+3)=LEN(A1))), SEARCH("mart", A1), 0), IF(SEARCH("mart", A1)=1, IF(OR(MID(A1, 5, 1)=" ", LEN(A1)=4), SEARCH("mart", A1), 0), 0))
```

Used it on the following test cases:

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. If "mart" is located somewhere in the text but not at the beginning of the text, then go to next condition. Else, go to condition 4.
2. If the character before it is a space, then go to next condition. Else, display 0.
3. If the character after it is a space or if it's the last "word" in the text, then display its location. Else, display 0.
4. If the character after it is a space or if it's the only "word" in the cell, then display 1. Else, display 0.